# How to Attach the Events of an Original Object to a Deep Copied Clone

Tags: .net, vb.net, events

Following up on my question yesterday to deepcopy an object with events in C# and attach the events of the original object to the Cloned copy is pretty easy, you just set the Event declaration in the Copy = the value in the original. [Deep Clone when events are attached](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4029600/performing-a-deepcopyclone-when-events-are-attached)

How do you do this in VB.Net? (Using .Net 2)

I was hoping maybe there was something with reflection where you can examine what events are bound and somehow transfer those to the new object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

yes you can, and its not that difficult, but it seems there isint a whole lot of info on this, so great question.

```
Dim sourceObject As New FooBar
Dim destObject As New FooBar

AddHandler sourceObject.SomeEvent, AddressOf myFunc


Dim miHandler As FieldInfo = GetType(FooBar).GetField("SomeEvent", BindingFlags.Static Or BindingFlags.NonPublic Or BindingFlags.Instance)
Dim sourceDelegate As [Delegate] = miHandler.GetValue(sourceObject)

Dim addDelegate As [Delegate] = sourceDelegate.GetInvocationList().First() ' if its multicast, then you'll need to copy the lot

AddHandler destObject.SomeEvent, addDelegate
```

Comment: Do you know if this works with asp.net?  I've had no luck with .GetField("SomeEvent"), it always returns Nothing.

Comment: I believe this ALMOST works with asp.net with code-behind.  As the code-behind partial class is inherited into the final output page, you need to call `Me.GetType.BaseType`.  Maybe this comment will be useful for someone.