# How can I get an actual EventHandler delegate instance from an event in VB.NET?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, events, event-handling

In C#, I could do something like this:

```
EventHandler handler = this.SomeEvent;
```

...which would allow me to, for example, do:

```
Delegate[] attachedHandlers = handler.GetInvocationList();
```

In VB.NET, I can't seem to figure out how to do a similar thing.

This doesn't work:

```
Dim handler As EventHandler = Me.SomeEvent
```

...due to the following error:

> Public Event SomeEvent(sender As
>   Object, e As EventArgs)' is an event,
>   and cannot be called directly. Use a
>   'RaiseEvent' statement to raise an
>   event.

But this doesn't work either:

```
Dim handler As EventHandler = AddressOf Me.SomeEvent
```

...because:

> 'AddressOf' operand must be the name of a method (without parentheses).

So how can I actually get an `EventHandler` from an event in VB.NET? The only idea that's immediately coming to mind is to use reflection, but that seems pretty ridiculous.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
   Private Event MyEvent()
   Private delegates() As System.Delegate = MyEventEvent.GetInvocationList()
```

undocumented, found [here](http://bytes.com/topic/visual-basic-net/answers/368483-getinvocationlist-wheres-multi-cast-delgate-again)

Comment: Me neither! Seems to be one of the "don't-let-that-a-VB.Net-developer see"-things

Comment: I almost want to downvote it because it's so horrible, but obviously it's not your fault so I'll upvote instead :o)

Comment: You might prefer the explicit Custom Event declaration syntax described [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163775.aspx#S9).

Answer (score 1):

if you take a look at this [How to Attach the Events of an Original Object to a Deep Copied Clone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4038465/how-to-attach-the-events-of-an-original-object-to-a-deep-copied-clone/4052847) I have a code example on how to get the delegate for the event via reflection. As far as I know, its the only way to do it in VB.